# Add configurable products to cart from category page

Tags: magento2, category

Is there any way that we can add configurable product to cart from category page with their attributes, like color, size etc ? Right now when i add any configurable product to cart it redirects me on product page.

Answer (score 0):

There is default behaviour to allow you to do this

Within the sample data there is a colour and size attribute

See on luma theme how these can be shown on category product listing page

https://magento.nublue.co.uk/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html

You see how you can select size and colour and you can add to basket.

I recommend you investigate the luma theme and sample data

Comment: is there any configuration on backend for this>

Comment: Take a look at colour and size attribute codes.  Plus this https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/configure-color-swatches-in-magento-2/ and this https://www.aitoc.com/blog/adding-clothing-size-options-magento-2/

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i am not sure what you want to say, i mean i have asked that i want to add products to cart from category page but you have shared links of "Adding Clothing Size Options in Magento 2".

Comment: Yes I could have been clearer.  That's backend configuration of the attributes - there is no backend configuration to bring through on template.  Luma theme picks up on these attributes automatically.

Comment: i am still confused, I don't know how it would be possible. this is my category page. you please brief step by step i would appreciate.http://i.imgur.com/42cqgdN.png